# Redux - Angular: How prevent actions called twice?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

Redux It's a very cool library, I really like it, but how can I prevent that actions call twice? What mistakes can generate this behavior ?
Consider that I've already unsubscribe the subscription into the controller

```
constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.subscription = this._store.select('reduxObj').subscribe(function (item) {
      switch (item.type) {
        case fromAction.GETITEMS: {
          break;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._store.dispatch(new fromAction.GetListAction());
  }



    //REDUCER
    export function ReduxReducer(state: any = undefined, action: fromAction.actions) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case fromAction.GETITEMS: {
      return { ...state, type: fromAction.GETITEMS }
    }
  }


  //ACTION
  export class GetListAction implements Action {
    readonly type = GETITEMS;
    constructor() { }
  }
```

Comment: why is `this._store.select('reduxObj')` in constructor, it should be in init method

Comment: You would need to expand on your question really. Unless you're using effects that call actions, you have full control over when you dispatch an action so not sure what you mean by 'actions call twice'. Also your example is strange. You should really use created selectors in you store.select. Then doing a switch on type is illogical. You might want to read up a bit more on how to implement NGRX I think.

Comment: putting the redux into the ngonInit() actions are called  thrice instead twice. 
I really can't understand the behaviur

Comment: skip the code if you don't get it , but please consider that works fine, but the question was  : What mistakes can generate this behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People seem to focus on trivial things.

So I'll straight answer your question :

a `select` on a store listens to `dispatch` events in its most simple implementation.

You call `dispatch` twice, your subscription gets called twice.

Now this can change with effects and so on, but I'll assume you don't have any.

If it gets called twice, it's because your store is instantiated with a default value. In your reducers signature is

```
(state: MyState, action: MyAction implements Action) => any
```

And generally, you put it like this

```
myReducer(state: MyState = undefined, action: MyAction implements Action) { ... }
```

This means that you have your first value being `undefined`, and if you call dispatch, your second value is defined.

That's where the two calls come from.

And as a side note, you can leave it in the constructor, that won't change a damn thing.

#### EDIT

To ignore the first value, you can use `filter` or `skip` (not all at once, choose one depending on what you want) :

```
this.subscription = this._store.select('reduxObj').pipe(
  // For an array, will ignore all empty arrays
  filter(value => value.length),
  // For undefined, will ignore all falsy values
  filter(value => !!value),
  // Ignore first value only
  skip(1),
)
```

Comment: it makes sence, who can generate an undefined value ? I updated my code above thanks

Comment: mine is `undefined`, yours is `state: any = []`, so you will have two values emitted, the first being `[]` and the second being `new fromAction.GetListAction()`.

Comment: I tried and I uploaded the code above but i have the same behavior.

Comment: Of course, that's exactly the same behavior. I have updated my question, try this out and tell me what you choose !

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need to `.bind(this)` to observer function. Secondly, you are able to take advantage from ES6 arrow functions instead of regular javascript functions as a callback (`() => {}`).

When it comes to your question - the best option to take only one value from Observable is adding `take()` stage to the RxJS pipe, like that:

```
         this.subscription = this._store.select('reduxObj')
           .pipe(take(1))
           .subscribe((item) => {
              switch (item.type) {    
                case fromAction.GETITEMS:{                                                                                                        
                  //...                                    
                  break;
                }
              }
        });
```

To use it you have to import take from 'rxjs/operators' assuming you're using RxJS 5.5 library or above.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```