# ngrx store initiated twice

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I noticed that actions are dispatched twice , So I realized the reason was that the store was initiated twice based on this answer : '[Redux - Angular: How prevent actions called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298830/redux-angular-how-prevent-actions-called-twice)'

I tried that in reducer function :

```
...
default: {
  console.log(action);
  return state;
}
```

These are the actions :

```
 {type: "@ngrx/store/init"}

 {type: "@ngrx/effects/init"}
```

my imports in app.module.ts :

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ auth: authReducer }),

EffectsModule.forRoot([ AuthEffects ]),
```

so how I can prevent one of those initiations ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's fine and by design, the first one is for reducers and the second one is for effects, because effects are initialized later than the store and it's too later for `@ngrx/store/init`. therefore in effects initialization is done on `@ngrx/effects/init`.